# Making Aspectj work on a Spring servlet bean

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get an aspectprofiler working on a Jersey servlet registered in a spring project. The aspectprofiler is loaded, but don't notice when methods within the Jersey servlet are run.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpringApplicationBuilder sab = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ConsolidatedCustomerMasterApp.class);
        sab.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        final ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public AspectProfiler profiler() {
        return new AspectProfiler();
    }
}
```

...

```
public class JerseyInitialization extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyInitialization() {
        packages("com.example.package");
    }
```

...

```
package com.example.package;

//imports
@Path("/test")
public class RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

...

```
@Aspect
public class AspectProfiler {
    private static final DefaultApplicationProfiler PROFILER = new DefaultApplicationProfiler(
        Arrays.<ProfilerOperator> asList(
            new StatsdProfilerOperator(),
            new LoggingProfilerOperator())
            );

    private static final String REST_MATCHER =
            "execution(* com.example.package..*.*(..))";

    @Around(REST_MATCHER)
    public Object around(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("test");
        return PROFILER.around(joinPoint);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your Jersey resource classes need to be managed by Spring also. Add `@Component` to them, and `@ComponentScan` for them

Comment: I tried this. The Aspectj method runs. However, on the client side, I receive a 404, and on the server side, the following errors appear

`2015-11-11 10:44:18.776  WARN 596 --- [tp2019461124-21] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   :
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

`2015-11-11 10:44:18.817  WARN 596 --- [tp2019461124-21] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /test/test
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of making the Jersey resource classes Spring `@Component`s (and `@ComponentScan`ing for them), you also need to make the `ResourceConfig` a Spring `@Component` also. You can see in the [Spring Boot `JerseyAutoConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java#L76) that it autowires the `ResourceConfig`, which it uses for the `ServletContainer` registration.

One thing to also note is that it creates its own `ServletRegistrationBean`

```
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new ServletContainer(this.config), this.path);
    addInitParameters(registration);
    registration.setName("jerseyServlet");
    return registration;
}
```

When you declare your own, you are overriding this one. You are not adding any special functionality that is not already provided, so just leave the default. Any Jersey specific configurations can be added in the `application.properties` file or through code configurations.

As for dependencies, I'll just assume you have all the right dependencies. The following are what I used to test

```
<!-- all 1.2.7.RELEASE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**See Also:**

- [spring-boot-sample-jersey - from project samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey)
- [§26.2 JAX-RS and Jersey - from Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me sort out my problems.