# Not able to intercept jersey resource method using writerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to intercept the jersey resource method using writer interceptor. But it is not working for me.

**Custom Annotation**

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TransactionMonitored {
  String name() default "";
}
```

**Interceptor class**

```
@TransactionMonitored
@Provider
public class TestInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

   @Override
   public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      context.proceed();
   }
}
```

**Resource method**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Air Avail Message Response", notes = "Returns Air Avail Response for Input XML Request", response = AirAvailResponseType.class)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,CommonConstants.Fastinfoset})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,CommonConstants.Fastinfoset})
@POST
@TransactionMonitored
public Response execute(AirAvailRequestType airAvailRequestType, @Context HttpContext HttpContext) {
    Exchange<AirAvailRequestType, AirAvailResponseType> padExchange = new Exchange<>(airAvailRequestType);
    ExecutionContext context = null;
    try {
```

First I have used Spring AOP method interceptor for intercepting the above resource method and identified that I am not able to intercept the resource method, registered in jersey. So I tried this jersey interceptor. Can anyone please check and let me know whether I am missing anything or not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the interceptor? The WriterInterceptor is not meant to be an AOP style interceptor.

Comment: I am trying to implement transaction monitoring using custom annotations. Using spring method interceptor we can check the response of method invocation.proceed() and add monitors. But I am not able to implement spring method interceptor to these jersey resource method, as it is throwing '404 error'. From the documentation I understood that filters and interceptors are use to modify headers and method contents, but i was just checking whether I will get response of method using writer interceptor, so that I can use the response for monitoring. Is it possible?

Comment: You can implement AOP with Jersey's underlying IoC framework HK2. See [this example](https://github.com/mgajdos/jersey-intercepting-resource-methods), and [heres the documentation](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/extensibility.html#Interception)

Comment: As far as Spring goes, you are probably not implementing it correctly. I have no problem using Spring AOP integration with Jersey. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33625937/2587435), to see it is possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using aspectj. I will try with the links you provided and let you know.

Comment: Also if all you need is the response entity Java object, you can just write a `ClientResponseFilter` or a `WriterInterceptor`. Both you can call `getEntity()` from the context, which will just return an Object. If your current problem is that the interceptor is just not being called, then you will need to show your configuration.